# How does measurement affect multiple entangled qubits

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm trying to understand how measurement affects the non-measured qubits when I have more than two entangled qubits.

Question 1: Say I have three entangled qubits in the state `1/2 (|000> + |011> + |101> + |110>)`, i.e. an equal chance of any even parity bit pattern.  I then measure the left bit, and say it's 0.  Are the other two bits still entangled, or does the wave function collapse upon the measurement of any bit?

Question 2: Suppose I wrote the code:

```py
qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)
# Let the transpiler figure out how to get the entangled state
matrix = np.array((1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), dtype=float) / 2
qc.initialize(matrix)
qc.measure(0, 0)
# See text below
qc.measure((1, 2), (1, 2))
result = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator').run(qc).result()
```

In this code, I would get identical results whether or not the bits are entangled after the first measurement. Is there something I could add to the code above that would distinguish entangled qubits from qubits forced to be `|0>` or `|1>`.

Question 3. Suppose, instead, my state were `A|000> + B|011> + C|101> + D|110>`, and I measured the left bit to be `0`. The new state is `A'|001> + B'|110>`.  Are A' and B' just A and B multiplied by the appropriate scale factor so the norm is 1?  Is there a phase shift of any sort?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the details of Quantum Teleportation answer my question.  Measuring one qubit simply magically puts other qubits into a state that is consistent with that measurement, but does not cause their state to collapse.